# How to Make a Discord Music Bot Using Discord.py Cogs

Tags: python-3.x, audio, discord.py

### My Current Project

I'm trying to convert a Python music bot I made off a YouTube video into a cog, so my main Python Discord bot file isn't so cluttered.

### My Problem

The code below I wrote isn't working. I read the docs on cogs, but I can't seem to find what I did wrong.

Here's the code I tried making, but it

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import youtube_dl
import os
from time import sleep
 
rpgmusicpath = r"path\to\music.mp3"
 
class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.bot = client
 
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Music cog successfully loaded.')
       
       
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def rpgmusic(ctx, self):
        global voice
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
 
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
 
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
            print(f'Bot connected to voice channel {channel}\n')
   
        await ctx.send(f'Playing some RPG music in {channel}.')
        sleep(3)
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('rpgmusic.mp3'), after=lambda e: print(f'RPG music in {channel} has finished playing.'))
        voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
        voice.source.volume = 0.05
 
   
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def join(ctx, self):
        global voice
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
 
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.move_to(channel)
 
        else:
            voice = await channel.connect()
            print(f'Bot connected to voice channel {channel}\n')
 
        await ctx.send(f'I joined {channel}.')
   
 
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def leave(ctx, self):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
   
        if voice and voice.is_connected():
            await voice.disconnect()
            print(f'Bot disconnected from channel {channel}.')
       
        else:
            print('Not able to disconnect to a voice channel because bot wasn\'t in one.')
       
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def play(ctx, url: str, self):
        song_there = os.path.isfile('song.mp3')
        try:
            if song_there:
                os.remove('song.mp3')
                print('Removed current song.')
        except PermissionError:
            print('Error in deleting song file. (Song in use.)')
            await ctx.send('Unable to request song. (Song already in use.)')
            return
   
        await ctx.send('Preparing song. Please wait.')
        voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
 
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                    'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                    'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            print('Downloading audio now.\n')
            ydl.download([url])
 
        for file in os.listdir('./'):
            if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                name = file
                print(f'Renamed File: {file}.')
                os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
 
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'), after=lambda e: print(f'{name} has finished playing.'))
        voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
        voice.source.volume = 0.06
 
        nname = name.rsplit('-', 2)
        await ctx.send(f'Now playing {name}.')
        print('Now playing.\n')
 
 
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems :

- You didn't replaced `bot` by `self.bot`.

In `rpgmusic`, `join`, `leave` and `play` commands, change :

```py
voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

To :

```py
voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

- Your first argument must be `self`, and not `ctx`:

```py
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def rpgmusic(self, ctx)

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(self, ctx)

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(self, ctx)
```

Also, since you have a `join` function, you can await it in `rpgmusic` (you also don't need `global voice`):

```py
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def rpgmusic(ctx, self):
        await self.join(ctx)
        await ctx.send(f'Playing some RPG music in {channel}.')
        sleep(3)
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('rpgmusic.mp3'), after=lambda e: print(f'RPG music in {channel} has finished playing.'))
        voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
        voice.source.volume = 0.05
```

Comment: It still isn't joining. And even worse, I'm not getting any errors in the console. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much. That got it all working. And, as for the example, I think I'll stick with downloading it. Playing directly from YT makes static, and isn't very high quality. I'd rather wait a little and have good quality than have more time and have bad quality. But thanks anyway.